# Solving $N\equiv1\pmod2,N\equiv2\pmod3,\dots,N\equiv n-1\pmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If I have:
\begin{align*}
N &\equiv 1 &\pmod{2}\\
N &\equiv 2 &\pmod{3}\\
N &\equiv 3 &\pmod{4}\\
&\vdots\\ 
N &\equiv n - 1 &\pmod{n}
\end{align*}
How could I solve for $N$? Is there any property relates to this problem?

**Update**
Base on Moron hint, we have:
\begin{align*}
N + 1 &\equiv 0 &\pmod{2}\\
N + 1 &\equiv 0 &\pmod{3}\\
N + 1 &\equiv 0 &\pmod{4}\\
\vdots\\
N + 1 &\equiv 0 &\pmod{n}
\end{align*}
Hence, 
$$N + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{\mathrm{lcm}(2\cdot 3\cdots n}$$

$$\therefore N + 1 = lcm(2.3.4...n) * k \text{ for some integers k } $$
$$\implies N = lcm(2.3.4...n) * k - 1$$

Does it look right?

Thanks,
Chan

Comment: $N = k \times \text{lcm}(1,2,\ldots,n)-1$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Comment: @Sivaram Ambikasaran: Thanks, but could you explain how it works? I know there is a property for $\pmod{lcm}$, but in this case the right hand side parts are different. It goes from 1 -> n - 1.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: Thanks for the link

Comment: @Chan: As Qiaochu points out this is nothing but a special case of Chinese Remainder Theorem. your $N \equiv -1 \bmod m$,  $\forall m \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$

Comment: @Sivaram Ambikasaran: Thanks.

Comment: @Chan: Yes, the result is correct now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Consider the possible values for $N+1$.

Comment: I got it ;) So simple. Many thanks.